# что конкретно представляет из себя нейронная сеть?

Tags: нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Я бы хотел получить конкретный "человеческий" ответ на вопрос "**Что такое нейронная сеть?**" и ответы на свои несколько вопросов, то есть не цитату из книги, и не пояснение из википедии.

- Это отдельный язык программирования? Или это специальный сложный алгоритм или последовательность математических действий, который можно встроить в любую среду? Или же это библиотека, доступная для некоторых языков программирования?
- Чем нейронная сеть отличается от алгоритмов, которые имитируют ботов и виртуальных сущностей?
- Принцип работы нейронных сетей на разных языках программирования - одинаковый? Если да, то как, допустим, перенести "робота" из одной среди разработки в другую?
- Если я захочу скачать готового бота, нужно ли мне знать язык программирования на, котором он написан, чтобы обучать его? Или же, если в нём присутствуют базовые "функции мышления", то его остается только обучать?

Да, знаю, вопрос, наверное, странный и в некоторых моментах глупый, но что есть то есть.

- И ещё вопрос на засыпку: последние 2 года происходит какой-то бум этих нейронных сетей - это временная шумиха? Или же это новая индустрия, которая придет на замену привычным технологиям?

Comment: Последние 2 месяца меня интересует этот вопроссс

Comment: А что вы пытались по своим вопросам гуглить ? Вот например по запросу "Нейронная сеть язык" (ваш первый вопрос) в первой же статье написано, что сети пишутся на куче языков и да, конечно есть куча готовых библиотек. А так как это библиотека, то для пользования ей конечно надо знать язык для которого она сделана. Если вы найдете код конкретной сети (ее структура и формулы используемые при обучении (математический аппарат) рассчитаны под определенные задачи) и ваша задача будет соответствовать тому на что рассчитана данная программа, то конечно вы сможете ее обучить

Comment: По последнему пункту ... вы как то слишком категоричны (как и в первых вопросах). смотрите шире. Нет четкого ИЛИ то ИЛИ другое. Да, нейронные сети развиваются, да у них становится больше возможностей и да, пожалуй это новая индустрия. но с чего бы ей _заменять_ существующие технологии. каждая технология хороша для решения своего круга задач. Есть круг задач, которые удобно решать сетями и есть совершенно другие задачи, которые удобно решать совершенно другими технологиями. так что мы наблюдаем рождение новых технологий в дополнение к существующим

Comment: [Неплохой ответ есть у XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1838/) :)

Answer (score 1):

Нейронная сеть -

> математическая модель, работающая подобно нашему мозгу

Грубо говоря, она состоит из слоёв, которые состоят из нейронов, каждый из которых получает информацию из предыдущего слоя и передаёт следующему.

Нет, это не специальный язык программирования, то - сможете ли вы её обучать без знания языка зависит от самой сети. Но лучше знать язык, на котором вы создаёте / обучаете сеть...

Боты и сущности похожие на людей и есть нейронные сети и да вероятно недавно началось начало новой индустрии, когда создают кучу этих "нейронных сетей", потому что они очень хорошая альтернатива к людям работающим "на телефоне" (тех. поддержка и т.п)

На Stack Overflow есть специальный форум, где подробно отвечают на такого рода вопросы (Artificial Intelligence называется).